# Unit Testing RxJava doOnSubscribe and doFinally

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rx-java2

How do I create a unit test that a certain side effect is done on `doOnScubscribe` and `doFinally` of an rxjava chain?

For Example:

```java
Observable.requestSomeValueFromWeb()
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> showLoading = true)
            .doFinally(() -> showLoading = false)
            .subscribe(result -> doSomething(result), error -> doErrorHandling(error));
```

How do I test in the scenario above that the `showLoading` was set to true on subscribe and false when the observable was disposed?

```java
TestSubscriber<WebServiceResponse> loginRequestSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

clientLoginViewModel.requestLogin().subscribe(loginRequestSubscriber);

// check that showLoading was true when webservice was called
assertEquals(true, showLoading);

// check that showLoading was false when webservice was finished
assertEquals(false, showLoading);

loginRequestSubscriber.assertSubscribed();
```

Comment: why not add a println in your code? something like .doOnSubscribe(() -> {showLoading = true; print("inside doOnSubscribe"); })...

Comment: I was not reffering to just checking it manually. I was actually reffering to UNIT TESTING. How to write the code to test this behavior. Let me make my question more clear.

Comment: You can take the `Disposable` returned by `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` from it between your 2 asserts. The final assert should be removed.

Comment: clientLoginViewModel.requestLogin() returns a Single. I believe by the time time of subscription everything happens so fast that by the time it reaches the first assertion the Single would have reached the doFinally chain, the showLoading would then be false and the assertion would fail by then.

Comment: assert the disposables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, your Object Under Test is the `ClientLoginViewModel`, so I'm trying to work from there. Let me know if I'm mistaken and I can revisit my answer:

The classes from your system:

```java
interface WebServiceResponse { } // We don't care about this here

interface Network {
    // This is whatever interacts with the Network, and we'll mock it out
    Single<WebServiceResponse> requestSomeValue();
}

// The class we are testing
class ClientLoginViewModel {

    final Network mNetwork;

    // This is the field we want to check... you probably want to make it
    // private and have accessors for it
    boolean showLoading;

    // This allows dependency injection, so we can mock :)
    ClientLoginViewModel(final Network network) {
        mNetwork = network;
    }

    // The actual method to test!
    Single<WebServiceResponse> requestLogin() {
       return mNetwork.requestSomeValue()
           .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> showLoading = true)
           .doFinally(() -> showLoading = false);
    }
}
```

And now the test!!!

```java
class ClientLoginViewModelTest {

    @Test
    public void testLoading() {
        final Network network = mock(Network.class);
        final WebServiceResponse response = mock(WebServiceResponse.class);

        // This is the trick! We'll use it to allow us to assert anything
        // before the stream is done
        final PublishSubject<Boolean> delayer = PublishSubject.create();
        when(network.requestSomeValue())
            .thenReturn(
               
 Single.just(response).delaySubscription(publishSubject)
            );

        final ClientLoginViewModel clientLoginViewModel = new ClientLoginViewModel(network);

        clientLoginViewModel
            .requestLogin()
            .test();

        // check that showLoading was true when webservice was called
        assertEquals(true, clientLoginViewModel.showLoading);

        // now let the response from the Network continue
        publishSubject.onComplete();

        // check that showLoading was false when webservice was finished
        assertEquals(false, clientLoginViewModel.showLoading);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! This is exactly what i'm trying to do! can you explain to me what '.test()' does? please?

Comment: `test()` is just a convenient operator for tests that turns a `TestSubscriber`. In this case, doing a `.subscribe()` would have worked, but I try to use the most semantic operator when possible. More info here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#testing